# Get all hierarchical root elements name for an xml child

Tags: java, jquery, xml

I have an xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Root>
    <Menu title="Menu 1" url="root_pages.php?id=1">
        <SubMenu title="sub 1" url="pages.php?id=1" />
        <SubMenu title="sub 2" url="pages.php?id=2" />
        <SubMenu title="sub 3" url="pages.php?id=3" />
        <SubMenu title="sub 4" url="pages.php?id=4" />
        <SubMenu title="sub 5" url="pages.php?id=5" />
    </Menu>
    <Menu title="Menu 2" url="root_pages.php?id=2">
        <SubMenu title="sub 6" url="pages.php?id=6" />
        <SubMenu title="sub 7" url="pages.php?id=7" />
    </Menu>
    <Menu title="Menu 3" url="root_pages.php?id=3">
    </Menu>
</Root>
```

Now I am trying to do something like for every element I can get the full hierarchy path (like breadcrumb).

For example if I take  `<SubMenu title="sub 3>` this element, the result will be : root/Menu 1/sub3

Is there any simple and easy way to do this?

Thanks,
Surodip

Comment: Maybe I've been living under a rock and missed something but... What IDE are you using that allows JQuery with Java? JQuery to the best of my knowledge has always been a Javascript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = $.parseXML($("pre").html());
var xml = $(data.documentElement);
var res = "";
var elem = xml.find("[title='sub 3']");
elem.parents().add(elem).each(function(i, el) {
  res += ($(el).attr("title") || el.tagName) + "/"
});
$("body").prepend(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<Root>
    <Menu title="Menu 1" url="root_pages.php?id=1">
        <SubMenu title="sub 1" url="pages.php?id=1"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="sub 2" url="pages.php?id=2"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="sub 3" url="pages.php?id=3"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="sub 4" url="pages.php?id=4"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="sub 5" url="pages.php?id=5"></SubMenu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu title="Menu 2" url="root_pages.php?id=2">
        <SubMenu title="sub 6" url="pages.php?id=6"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="sub 7" url="pages.php?id=7"></SubMenu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu title="Menu 3" url="root_pages.php?id=3">
    </Menu>
</Root>
</pre>
```